# Collider not working after changing object scale

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

In my 2d game, no collider is working after changing it's scale.
My Spaceship/Sprite is surrounding with Box collider 2D. Now I want to use border and that's why using Cube and Cylinder object. Where I used Box collider 2D then it's working fine. But when I am changing Cube/Cylinder scale[my intent is to use one cube to cover whole border] then it's not working and my Spaceship go through into that Cube/Cylinder object. I have also tried different type of
collider but after scaling no one is working.

I am  using a BoxCollider2D on the cube (wall).

I am changing the cube's transform's local y scale in the inspector:

[image]

Comment: does your collider appear to be getting bigger when you change the scale?

Comment: yes it's getting bigger, but thing is when Y value is bigger than 1 it's not working

Comment: Try to create a [mre] for this bug if you can. It's still very unclear how things arrived here.

Comment: I am unable to recreate this so it would be helpful if you can provide what Ruzihm has asked.

Comment: @Edge ofcourse you're right ^^

Comment: This could also be an issue of how you are moving the ship

Comment: Is it maybe due to not updating the collider `size`? For BoxCollider.size the docs explicitly state it is measured in local space of the object ... For BoxCollider2D.size it doesn't... Is this maybe different for 2D? (No 2D expert)

Comment: @derHugo if you increase the scale of an object it modifies the local space of the object.  This could be an issue if he was change the scale of a child object, and the box collider was on a parent.

Comment: @M.S.T can you change the screenshot so that it shows all of the components on the gameobject whose localscale you're changing?

Comment: Honestly, I only know of a few ways to break collision, 1 is to change the scale of a static marked object, the other is to change the scale on a child object rather instead of the parent, and lastly is to directly update an object position rather then using the built-in systems.

Comment: please check my updated screenshot.
I am trying to large my cube size and after scaling of Y value it is getting bigger but when my Spaceship moving here it go through the cube. It's make me strange coz when the Y value is '1' it's collide with my Spaceship but after Y value increase go through into that

Comment: @AresCaelum and Ruzihm am I clear to you both now? in my Screenshot black circle value I am changing and it causes the matter

Comment: Does the same happen if you only change the size of the collider without changing the object scale?

Comment: We are clear, however I can't recreate your issue which is why @Ruzihm asked for a MRE

Comment: @derHugo yes it's remain same even I changed the collider size without changing the object scale

Comment: @M.S.T Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Ruzihm Not yet, alternatively I am using coordinate axis limit through script

Answer (score 0):

As I am not getting a proper answer so I have changed my mind to solve the problem in a different way.
Here I am using the coordinate axis to check the border. Now my Spaceship doesn't go outside of screen.

```
public Rigidbody2D player;
private Vector2 screenBounds;
private float playerWidth;
private float playerHeight;

void Start()
{
    player = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    playerWidth = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x / 2;
    playerHeight = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y / 2;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    MovePlayer();
}

public void MovePlayer()
{
    player.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    this.transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, 0);

    Vector3 viewPos = transform.position;
    viewPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(viewPos.x, -screenBounds.x + playerWidth, screenBounds.x - playerWidth);
    viewPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(viewPos.y, -screenBounds.y + playerHeight, screenBounds.y - playerHeight);
    transform.position = viewPos;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use `Collider`s as a component attached to a scaled `GameObject`, whether the scaling is positive or negative (the latter having even worse results). I've found this time and again.

For `BoxCollider` (unlike `MeshCollider`), you have options if you really *need* to have a scaled object; both of which involve creating a separate, unscaled `GameObject` with `*Collider` attached:

1. Create a container object that is scaled `(1,1,1)` with `BoxCollider` on it. Then create your scaled `GameObject` (the renderable `Mesh`) as a child therein. This way you get the scaled look and a working collider. Adjust parent's `BoxCollider.size` as required to fit model.
2. Create both as siblings in the hierarchy / scene graph. This is a little cheaper on CPU, as you are performing fewer recursive transformations, but it can get messy, scene-wise.

If you're scaling dynamically i.e. in code, then in both of the above cases, as you adjust the scale on the child, you will need to adjust the `BoxCollider.size` on the parent to match that scale.